# (Unity) semaphore.wait for signal android slows down my game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am building my first game in android. When I play in the editor everything works fine, but when I build and run I get huge lag to the point where it is unplayable. I have attached the profiler and it looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this please?

Comment: Why are you thread syncing?

Comment: @Immersive I didn't even know that I was. I am also not sure what that is or how to turn that off. Would you be able to elaborate or link a useful page? Also how did you know that I was thread syncing?

Comment: Oh... I assumed you were the one who added the semaphores. (Semaphores are used for signalling between threads)  If it's not in your own code, I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: No guarantees, but you may find this interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/i0bo2b/how_do_you_trace_whats_holding_up/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to Multithread Rendering. After disabling `Multithread Rendering` in `Player` settings a Semaphore.waitForSignal not appeared in profiler anymore.

By the way it doens't fixed the issue with CPU performance and enabling such option looks reasonable for devices with multiple or advanced (more than 1 thread) cores. But at least it helped to face with another errors for investigation the root cause ^^